# How do you check the Liferay version in a FreeMarker template?

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme, liferay-7.2, liferay-7.3

I am working on a theme for Liferay that I wish to work with both versions 7.2 and 7.3 of Liferay. How can I check what version is being used within the template, so I can do code like this:

```freemarker
    <#if liferay_version == "7.3">
      <p>Liferay 7.3</p>
    <#elseif liferay_version == "7.2">
      <p>Liferay 7.2</p>
    </#if>
```

**Update (21/08):**
I have tried the using `assign` to get the service (as `set` can't be used in the template), but `serviceLocator` is `null`. `<#assign releaseLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalService")>`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
set ($releaseLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalService"))
#set ($release = $releaseLocalService.getRelease(1))
#set ($vers = $release.getBuildNumber())

<span class="simpleVersion">$vers</span>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work for me, it just shows the text as is in the page

Comment: don't you use `$vers` as you want? @SamWM

Comment: $vers is never set, either in init_custom.ftl or portal_normal.ftl

Answer (score 0):

Pratiks answer should work *if* you port it from Velocity to Freemarker *and* remove `serviceLocator` from the set of restricted variables (Control Panel -> Configuration -> System Settings -> Template Engines -> Freemarker):

```
<#assign 
  releaseLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalService")
  release = releaseLocalService.getRelease(1)
  vers = release.getBuildNumber()
/>
<span class="simpleVersion">${vers}</span>
```

If you don't want to go the route of allowing anyone with the permissions of editing templates on your Liferay instance to basically load *any* service and therefore *any* data on the server (because if you make the serviceLocator unrestricted, it will be available even in Page Fragment Templates)... well, then you will need to inject the variables you need using a `TemplateContextContributor`: [Simply create a new Liferay Module](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/creating-modules-with-liferay-ide), selecting 'template-context-contributor' as Project Template to derive from, then edit its main class to follow the code below. Also, you'd need to write the `MyHelper` class yourself (in the same module) and annotate that one with `@Component(immediate = true, service = MyHelper.class)`.

```
package my.own.template.context.contributor;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.template.TemplateContextContributor;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import my.own.template.object.MyHelper;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = "type=" + TemplateContextContributor.TYPE_GLOBAL,
    service = TemplateContextContributor.class
)
public class MyDisplayTemplateContextContributor
    implements TemplateContextContributor {

  @Override
  public void prepare(Map<String, Object> contextObjects, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    contextObjects.put("myHelper", _myHelper);
  }

  @Reference(unbind="-")
  MyHelper _myHelper;

}
```

After deploying that module, all Freemarker templates in your Liferay instance shall have the variable `myHelper`, with all public methods you add in the class `MyHelper` -- one of them could return the revision number you need.